# How to properly get KeyPair from the LocalKeystore

Tags: substrate-node

#### Background

I am currently working on a gadget for substrate that runs another software embedded within the node itself. This is similar to the [beefy gadget](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/d6e9c579ca8608a002de31771962f080581fa098/client/consensus/beefy). However, the software I'm using was originally designed to run as a standalone binary, rather than as substrate-specific software. The gadget serves as a thin wrapper around it and communicates with substrate using subxt over RPC.

#### Question

In order for this software to function properly and be able to sign/send transactions to the substrate node, it requires access to the SURI/Private Key. However, there doesn't seem to be a clear way to extract the raw private key seed from the keystore itself. The gadget has access to the `LocalKeystore`, which is passed to it as a parameter when starting it in the `service.rs` file.

#### Code I have tried

I have attempted the following code:

```rust
use sp_application_crypto::{key_types, sr25519, ByteArray, CryptoTypePublicPair, Pair};

fn get_sr25519_pair(local_keystore: Option<Arc<LocalKeystore>>) -> Option<sr25519::AppPair> {
    let local_key_store = local_keystore.expect("failed to get local keystore");
    let sr25519_public = local_key_store
        .keys(key_types::ACCOUNT)
        .expect("failed to get keys")
        .into_iter()
        .find_map(|CryptoTypePublicPair(id, public_key)| {
            if id == sr25519::CRYPTO_ID {
                sr25519::AppPublic::from_slice(&public_key).ok()
            } else {
                None
            }
        })
        .expect("failed to get sr25519 public key");
    let pair = local_key_store
        .key_pair::<sr25519::AppPair>(&sr25519_public)
        .expect("failed to get sr25519 pair");
    tracing::warn!("Pair Found {}", pair.is_some());
    pair
}
```

The output of this code is `Pair Found false`, which means I was able to obtain the public key, but it fails to find its corresponding key pair. It's worth noting that the [`LocalKeystore::key_pair`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/d6e9c579ca8608a002de31771962f080581fa098/client/keystore/src/local.rs#L55-L64) method requires `P: AppPair`, so I cannot simply use `sr25519::Pair` here. This is inconvenient because the key is inserted into the keystore with `sr25519::Pair`, not `sr25519::AppPair`.

**Could you please guide me on how to obtain the private key/seed of the main account (key type is `acco`) from the keystore?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `AppCrypto` trait has [const ID: KeyTypeId](https://docs.rs/sp-application-crypto/24.0.0/sp_application_crypto/trait.AppCrypto.html) which determines which keys will be filtered when using [LocalKeystore::key_pair](https://docs.rs/sc-keystore/latest/sc_keystore/struct.LocalKeystore.html#method.key_pair). Since you're using `sp_application_crypto::sr25519::AppPair`, [which doesn't use key_types::ACCOUNT](https://docs.rs/sp-application-crypto/latest/sp_application_crypto/sr25519/struct.AppPair.html#associatedconstant.ID), `LocalKeystore::key_pair` can't find your key - assuming your key is inserted to keystore with `key_types::ACCOUNT` key type.

One solution is to construct appropriate `AppPair` using `app_crypto!` like so:

```rust
pub mod my_mod {
    use sp_application_crypto::{app_crypto, key_types::ACCOUNT};
    use sp_core::sr25519;

    app_crypto!(sr25519, ACCOUNT);
}
```

And then use it to get your private-public pair:

```rust
let pair = local_key_store.key_pair::<my_mod::Pair>(&sr25519_public);
```